# ladder-like record selection without looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like this, A and B as columns:

```
A    B
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    3
```

A record can be selected by defining a value for A. If the selected row has a value for B, the row whose A's value is equal to the record's B must also be selected, and if that selected record has a B it must again be selected and so on.

Example:
If the user queries for A = 3, the returned rows must be:

```
A    B
3    2
2    1
1    0
```

This is the output because of this condition: `A3` has a value for `B`; there is a record whose `A` is equal to the first row's `B` which is `2` and the second record's `B` is `1` which still has a matching record.

Is there a way this can be done without looping through the records?

Comment: Cte looks to be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive CTE to achieve this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

```
;WITH RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE A = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.* FROM RCTE r
    INNER JOIN Table1 t ON r.B = t.A
)
SELECT * FROM RCTE
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6d7f/1)**